# AWS i3 vs i2 instances , what differenctiates their performance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, i3

Referring to a [post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/now-available-i3-instances-for-demanding-io-intensive-applications/#:%7E:text=When%20compared%20to%20the%20I2,network%20bandwidth%20per%20CPU%20core.) in AWS on difference between AWS i2 instance and i3, it is essentially using Amazon Linux AMI on Intel E5-2686 v4 (Broadwell) processor, so what exactly makes difference in performance between i2 and i3 instances, provided same specs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Previous Generation Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/previous-generation/):

> Compared to **I2** instances, **I3** instances have over 4x higher I/O performance, over 2x higher disk throughput and 18% more SSD per CPU. I3 instances offer Non-Volatile Memory Express (NVMe) based SSDs offering lower disk latencies than I2. I3 offers the lowest price per read IOPS of all EC2 instances.

- Newer Intel Xeon Processors
- Better Storage per instance
- High Performance NVMe Instance Storage
- ENA Support
- Larger size (16.xlarge) with up to 15.2 TB of Storage
- Better Price per GB of Instance Storage
- Best Price per IOPS

Comment: this makes sense. I was also wondering that the amount of cost for using i3 instance for say medium enterprise using `i3.4xlarge 16 122 GB 3.8 TB (2 disks) $1.248 per hour` can reach upto $100,000. So whats stopping people literally replicating the system (say Intel E5-2686 v4 processors, 256GB memory and 4 TB HDD) which would cost lot less in capital as well as operations per year!

Comment: If you are seeking a discussion about the economics of using a Cloud provider, I would suggest you ask at: https://www.reddit.com/r/cloud